# Build table in WITH clause from csv

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql, subquery-factoring

I have a csv file that was dumped from the table. 
Now I want to build the table using WITH from that csv file.
I had tried by taking all the values of each column, separated by comma in separate variable and then inserting by doing union in WITH but that was not possible.

Is it possible by inserting into table with comma separated values without loop? 
Let say 
$roll_no = "1,2,3,4,5" 
$name = "name1,name2,name3,name4,name5" 
roll_no   name 
---------------
1         name1
2         name2
3         name3
4         name4
5         name5
Is there any other way to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: By a csv file dumped in a table do you mean it was placed in a table properly by one of the many inbuilt and user-buildable processes that mean each column in the csv file is a separate column in Oracle? It sounds like you don't mean that, in which case read up about SQL*Loader and external tables before continuing any further.

Comment: Or do you mean you've extracted the csv file and you're trying to do SQL queries with it?

Comment: @Ben yes, I have dumped to csv like <br/>

Comment: @Ben yes, I had dumped the table to csv like
1,name1
2,name2
3,name3
..

by doing  select col1 || ',' || col2 from table;
now I want to build the table in WITH because I don't want to create any physical table.

Comment: Please show us the structure of your CSV file(s).

Comment: Please see this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11721051/146325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can pass your comma seperated string like in given below way. This would convert entire comma separated string in different rows.

```
 SELECT trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) COLUMNS from t t, table    
(xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(valuestring,--put comma seperated string here
':','</e><e>')||  
 '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x   );
```